# Spring read-only transaction with locked table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc

My spring configuration:

```
  <jee:jndi-lookup id="testDataSource" jndi-name="java:testDS" />

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="testDataSource" />
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My Java method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List find() {
  jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM my_table;");
}
```

If I use the script below directly on the database (`MySQL`):

```
LOCK TABLES my_table WRITE;
```

and then try to run the java code with a read-only transaction, it's still waiting for the table to be unlocked.

Shouldn't it return the data since the transaction is set as read-only?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because WRITE lock prevents both reading and writing to a table from anyone not holding the lock. If you put READ instead, you will be able to execute your query.

BTW, readOnly does nothing in the database directly, it's just a hint to ORM layer that transaction is not expected to do any writing.

Comment: So when there's a insert or update in the database it will lock the table to be reading as well? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Yes: don't start the transaction at all. But then your data is in danger. Understanding this requires knowledge of basic principles concurrent programming. BTW, depending on the database engine you're using you may not have to lock the whole table but only the row you're changing. Mysql's Innodb engine is one such engine.